# What's the best way to move "a child up" in a .NET XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, xml

Given an XML structure like this:

```
<garage>
 <car>Firebird</car>
 <car>Altima</car>
 <car>Prius</car>
</garage>
```

I want to "move" the Prius node "one level up" so it appears above the Altima node.  Here's the final structure I want:

```
<garage>
 <car>Firebird</car>
 <car>Prius</car>
 <car>Altima</car>
</garage>
```

So given the C# code:

```
XmlNode priusNode = GetReferenceToPriusNode()
```

What's the best way to cause the priusNode to "move up" one place in the garage's child list?

Comment: why would you move the Prius up with its brake problems?

Comment: @Mike: you _do_ know that the `XmlDocument` class is the same for C# as for VB.NET, right? Calling it a "C# XmlDocument" was just a manner of speech, right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Get the previous sibling node, remove the node you want to move from its parent, and re-insert it before the sibling.

```
XmlNode parent = priusNode.ParentNode.
XmlNode previousNode = priusNode.PreviousSibling;
//parent.RemoveChild(priusNode);  // see note below
parent.InsertBefore(priusNode, previousNode);
```

Error handling ignored but would be required for real implementation.

**EDIT:** Per Mike's comment, the RemoveChild call is superfluous: as the docs say, "If the newChild *[in this case priusNode]* is already in the tree, it is removed from its original position and added to its target position."  Thanks Mike!

Comment: That is definitely straightforward and worked fine.  I also noticed that the RemoveNode() call is extraneous - InsertBefore() will just move it.

Comment: to make it more general and error safe, you should add a check to see if previousSibling really exists  (if (previousNode!=null) ... )

Answer (score -1):

Try

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.parentnode.aspx

```
XmlNode nodParent = priusNode.ParentNode;
```

Comment: can you explain more?  How can I use ParentNode to alter the sequence of <garage>'s children?